# How to grab a windows license key and add it to a text file

Tags: powershell, window

I am trying to create a script that grabs the windows 10 license key using this command:

powershell "(Get-WmiObject -query `select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey"

and then adding the results of that command to an existing text file on a USB drive.

I'm not sure how to capture or grab the line where the windows license key is displayed after the command finishes and then add it to a text file.

I've tried using the -add and ; after the first command and then using add-content E:\sample.txt but it seems the add-content command only lets you add something manually.

If I could do something like:

Add-content E:\sample.txt (`nlicense key)

Trying to grab the license key, append it into a new line in an existing text file.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out the right way to output the results into a text file:

powershell "(Get-WmiObject -query `select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey" | add-content E:\sample.txt

The | operator is the key. It allows the results of the first command to be used in the second command.